# Position background image vertically with relative positioning

Tags: css

I'm attempting to center this white box image vertically and horizontally, but using background-position-y: center doesn't seem to be working. Neither does background-position: center center; Any idea why?

```
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
    grid-columns: 1/2;
    max-height: 80%;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/K0Z9HpI.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Edit:

Here's my codepen, sorry someone edited this and removed the codepen link and added all the code manually, and it's harder to see that it's not vertically aligned when the code is embedded on Stack Overflow.

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/QWvWOgz

Comment: Can't tell, none of your images don't show up, if your image is bigger than your element view area then it won't center since there is not enough room

Comment: it works fine. try an image witout transparency to find out. (square with white borders is there anyway)

Comment: Sorry, someone edited my post and removed my Code Pen which made it harder to notice the alignment. I made the checkbox smaller so you can see it's top aligned and not vertically aligned.

Comment: You have .checkbox set to max 70%, did you mean this? Anyway, it is showing at 70% so there's a 'gap' beneath it. Did you want to set it at 100% but have the white square only 70% dimension?

Comment: Yes, I changed the .checkbox size so people could more easily see that it's not center aligned vertically. There are four rows each with checkboxes, and right now they're aligned with the top of the div. I need them to be centered vertically as well as horizontally.